# Multiple HTML Data Attributes in Body tag not recognized by IE9 or older

Tags: django, html, django-templates, internet-explorer-9

I'm filling my WebApp (Django) template variables in html body data attributes. So that I can access them later through Javascript:

```
<body data-node_ip={{NODE_IP}}>
<body data-node_port={{NODE_PORT}}>
```

Later in the Javascript code, I'm accessing the variables through jQuery's data method:

`var connection = $("body").data("node_ip") + $("body").data("node_port")`

This works well with all modern browsers (IE10, Chrome, FF).

**Problem:**

However it doesn't work with IE9 or older. IE9 only stores one single value associated to the  tag.

**My question:**

How do I store these template variables in my HTML document (without using Javascript / jQuery) so that they are also accessible down to IE9?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be valid. You can only have one body element. But you can and should put all the attributes on that single element:

```
<body data-node_ip={{NODE_IP}} data-node_port={{NODE_PORT}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you assign them different ids and access them like this:

```
var connection = $("#body1").data("node_ip") + $("#body2").data("node_port")
```